# Heroku Bad response from SSL Endpoint provider

Tags: ssl, heroku

Good morning,

I am attempting to update my SSL certificate on Heroku but keep on getting a error:

```
!  Bad response from SSL Endpoint provider. Please try again later.
```

I have gone though the steps to create a bundle multiple times with no luck. From what I can tell this can mean there is an issue with my certificate or that there is an issue with Herokus services. There is mention of the SSL Doctor tool provided by Heroku, but the Github repo says to use the Toolkit but I have not been able to find any documentation on what the command is or how to use it.

I thought about removing my current SSL key but I have been at this for weeks and I don't want SSL to be down for that long.

Anyone experience this before, or know how to use SSL Doctor (or if SSL Doctor will even help).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hm, have you tried contacting Heroku support with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. It turns out - I was using the Heroku gem to handle the operations. All I had to do was uninstall the Heroku gem, and then install the latest toolbelt from Heroku. The worst part about this problem was that it failed silently. :(

Comment: Yes, I finally found the Heroku ticket system and got the same info from them. I followed the instructions for installing the toolkit, they ignored the fact you need to uninstall the gem. I should have noticed the obvious, but yeah.